# Isekai where the main character is reincarnated as the sidekick and wears a magic scarf

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read a story where the ml reincarnated as the goofball side character in an otome game that has a modern style but with magic.  He somehow ends up being adopted (?) by the principal of his magic school and is living with her and her adult daughter.  He wears a magic accessory scarf that changes shape with magic that he uses to defeat some terrorists and save a classmate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the appearance of any of the characters?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure this is ***[Magical Explorer](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/e915ol0/magical-explorer-eroge-no-yuujin-kyara-ni-tensei-shita-kedo-game-chishiki-tsukatte-jiyuu-ni-ikiru)***.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/129305/Magical%E2%98%85Explorer__Eroge_no_Yuujin_Kyara_ni_Tensei_shita_kedo_Game_Chishiki_Tsukatte_Jiyuu_ni_Ikiru):

> There's a legendary Bishoujo Game that has become popular among Japanese gentlemen. Its name is "Magical☆Explorer" or MagiEro for short. The game's protagonist has a cheat-like power with 12 different beautiful heroines to flirt with, including additional 12 heroines from the DLC, a harem of 24 beauties. I have become that protagonist! Not. Instead, I have become the third-wheel character who always laughing like an idiot next to him. There's no heroine that would lay their eyes on me.
>
> But now I couldn't care less about the protagonist and his heroines. Why? Because I discovered magic. While I was using it, I have become interested in it. I want to master it. I want to become the strongest. Thus I have decided. I would abandon half my role as a protagonist's friend to train my magic and then I would beat the hell out of that cheat who can solo the Demon King.
>
> I was training with that thought in mind, but somehow I keep getting closer to the heroines and furthermore, I don't know why I keep encountering events like I am some Eroge's protagonist.

An unmarried salaryman is reincarnated as a supporting character in the world of an erotic video game he played. He's initially excited at the prospect of meeting the various heroines in the game, until he remembers that only the protagonist of the game gets to date them. His character, Takioto Kousuke, is the best friend of the protagonist, and serves as both comic relief and an intermediary between the protagonist and the heroines.

The protagonist and Takioto are due to attend Tsukuyomi Magic Academy, and shortly before that, Takioto receives a visit from the principal, Hanamura Marino, who tells him that she regards him as family, since his mother is her cousin, and invites him to live with her and her adult daughter, who teaches at the academy.

Takioto also has a large, magic scarf which can be used as a weapon. In one scene, one of the heroines is attacked by a group of men from an 'Evil God Cult' and Takioto saves her, making heavy use of the scarf for both defensive and offensive purposes.

[image]

[image]